# Google sheets Pivot Max for each Row label

Tags: google-sheets

I have a pivot table with different variables: Such as X, Y, Z.
Each of those, display different variables for age (sometimes each X, Y or Z might have different rows), each has a cost (spend)

What I would like to do is to, for each of those variables, find the age which spent the most.

Unlike Excel, referencing a pivot table is not dynamic, so it would not work to order by the amount spent and referencing the first cell.

Is there a way to do this?

By the way, it doesn't have to be based on the pivot table, it can also apply to the raw data, it's just something I tried but didn't really work.

[image: Image of the pivot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY(A2:C13, 
 "select *", 0), 
 "select max(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label max(Col3)''", 0), 
 {C2:C13, A2:B13}, {2, 3, 1}, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Don't know exactly how it works, but it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to do that for exactly the same example but with no max amount?

Comment: No amount called column. only type and category, I mean.

Comment: @JohnED yeah: `=QUERY(QUERY(A2:B13, 
 "select *", 0), 
 "select Col1, max(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label Col1 'Type', max(Col2) 'Category'", 0)` https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbfRD.png

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks bro!